# VS Code : Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to debug my SharePoint Framework web part in VS code using the Chrome Debugger extension but I am getting error message as `Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found`.

Also in Debug Console I am getting :

`SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from https://localhost:4321/temp/manifestsFile.js.map`

`SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js.map`

I tried both `Local workbench` as well as `Hosted workbench` configuration but getting the same error.

Below is my launch.json file :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
      "name": "Local workbench",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "https://localhost:4321/temp/workbench.html",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
      },
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Hosted workbench",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "webpack:///../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*",
        "webpack:///../../../../../src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
      },
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anybody please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the tutorial that i have followed - https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/debug-in-vscode

Comment: Hi @Rohit were you able to find a solution with David's suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after it had been working. The issue for me was that I opened code from the command line at a folder level one higher, or the parent of the project. Closing Code and reopening at the project level worked for me.

If you .vscode folder is not in the same folder as your src folder this is probably your issue.

Comment: Hi @David I am opening the project from terminal using this directory: C:\spfx\helloworld-webpart\src , will that restrict me from debugging the solution in VS code?